# What's the difference between a script and a function in MATLAB?

Tags: file, function, matlab

What are the differences between a MATLAB script file and a MATLAB function file?

Answer (score 22):

[This page](http://web.cecs.pdx.edu/%7Egerry/MATLAB/programming/scripts.html#scriptsVSfuncs) says,

> **Scripts versus Functions**
>
> Scripts are m-files containing MATLAB
> statements. MATLAB ``functions'' are
> another type of m-file. The biggest
> difference between scripts and
> functions is that functions have input
> and output parameters. Script files
> can only operate on the variables that
> are hard-coded into their m-file. As
> you can see, functions much more
> flexible. They are therefore more
> suitable for general purpose tasks
> that will be applied to different
> data.
>
> Scripts are useful for tasks
> that don't change. They are also a way
> to document a specific sequence of
> actions, say a function call with
> special parameter values, that may be
> hard to remember.
>
> There are more
> subtle differences between scripts and
> functions. A script can be thought of
> as a keyboard macro: when you type the
> name of the script, all of the
> commands contained in it are executed
> just as if you had typed these
> commands into the command window.
> Thus, all variables created in the
> script are added to the workspace for
> the current session. Furthermore, if
> any of the variables in the script
> file have the same name as the ones in
> your current workspace, the values of
> those variables in the workspace are
> changed by the actions in the script.
> This can be used to your advantage. It
> can also cause unwanted side effects.
>
> In contrast, function variables are
> local to the function. (The exception
> is that it's possible to declare and
> use global variables, but that
> requires and explicit action by the
> user.) The local scope of function
> variables gives you greater security
> and flexibility. The only way (besides
> explicitly declared global variables)
> to get information into and out of a
> function is through through the
> variables in the parameter lists.

**Example**

One of the main differences between a script and a function is access to variables in the workspace. For example, suppose in the workspace, you've defined two variables `a = 10` and `b = 20`. These variables are defined at the command line of the main prompt.

***Script file - display_mult.m***

`disp(a*b)`;

Typing `display_mult` would display the product of `a` and `b` in the workspace, i.e. `10*20` or `200`.

But if you defined a function, called display_mult defined in a file with the same name:

***Function file - display_mult.m***

```
function display_mult(a,b)
   disp(a*b);
end
```

You would have to include the two variables as arguments to the function call. So, `display_mult` would **not** work this time since `a` and `b` does not exist in the function's workspace. You would have to include them by running `display_mult(a,b)` which will display the desired result.

**Simple explanation**

Each statement in a script is equivalent to typing them out at the command window of MATLAB. You're just storing them before-hand in a file!

A function, on the other hand, takes in arguments and is a "new" workspace, separate from the main workspace.

**Note:** The `end` at the end of a function call is optional but I like to add it to make things organized. Of course, if you have multiple function definitions in a file they will all have to end with `end`. Also, you cannot have a script and a function definition in the same file.