# not able to define function in matlab showing error

Tags: matlab

I defined the following function in matlab:

```
function draw_snake(snake,food)
```

but matlab shows me an error message saying:

```
Error: Function definitions are not permitted in this context.
```

I am new to matlab and just installed it.

I am using MATLAB version 8.1.0.604.

Comment: And what is the context?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to correct "Function definitions are not permitted at the prompt or in scripts"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5969547/how-to-correct-function-definitions-are-not-permitted-at-the-prompt-or-in-scrip)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5972184/matlab-error-function-definitions-are-not-permitted-in-this-context)
The [docs](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/function.html) say

> "function [y1,...,yN] = myfun(x1,...,xM) declares a function named
>   myfun that accepts inputs x1,...,xM and returns outputs y1,...,yN.
>   This declaration statement must be the first executable line of the
>   function."

So,

```
function draw_snake(snake,food)
```

must be the first line in a script called `draw_snake.m`