# Function definitions are not permitted in this context

Tags: function, matlab

Ok, I am new in Matlab and I am currently working on some econometric script. Before I move to real econometrics I have to create a function that selects the data that I'm interested in. Although I managed to get that script to work by writing at a very structural level, I would like this script to be as universal as possible and therefore would like to divide it into specific functions. However, when I converted all this to one function, I keep getting the error "Function definitions are not permitted in this context".
Thanks in advance for your help.

```
function [probingArray] = extractData (data, startValue, numberOfPeriods)
    arrayHeight=size(data,1);

    for i=1:arrayHeight
        if Date(i)==startValue
            datePosition=i;
        end
    end

    n=1;

    for i=(datePosition-numberOfPeriods):datePosition
        probingArray(n,1)=n;
        probingArray(n,2)=UK(i);
        n=n+1;
    end
clear n i;
```

Comment: Duplicate/Related: [How to correct "Function definitions are not permitted at the prompt or in scripts"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5969547/how-to-correct-function-definitions-are-not-permitted-at-the-prompt-or-in-script), [matlab error: Function definitions are not permitted in this context](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5972184/52738), [What's the difference between a script and a function in MATLAB?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1695365/52738)

Comment: Is the code is it's OWN file?  BTW, you don't need the clear n, i if it is, since all function variables are local to the function and aren't visible from outside the function.

Answer (score 0):

make sure you respect matlab conventions

function [out1, out2, ...] = myfun(in1, in2, ...) declares the function myfun, and its inputs and outputs. The function declaration must be the first executable line of any MATLAB function.

from http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/function.html

Comment: Nope, Date is an array which is imported with a data set before this function is executed

Comment: there are two more lines on the top (outside the function). Does that matter?

Comment: a file called extractData.m? just checking the obvious here :)

Comment: if the first two lines are NOT comments, this is your problem

Comment: Well, the first one is a comment, while the second one loads the data. I commented it and apparently I don't get the error anymore.
I see now that I can't use anything outside the function in one file in Matlab. That's horrible. However, could you please tell me how can I call that function in other script? I presume I have to include the file with that function first..

Comment: Specifically, in the Matlab online doco (which pops up if you run `doc` at the Matlab command line), MATLAB > Getting Started > Programming > Scripts and Functions, and MATLAB > User Guide > Programming Fundamentals > Functions and Scripts should clear this up.