# Attempted to access sym(67); index out of bounds because numel(sym)=2

Tags: matlab

I am receiving the following error message:

> Attempted to access sym(67); index out of bounds because numel(sym)=2.

I have been working on this for three days. I looked for similar error, but it didn't help. My code is below:

```
filename='DriveCyclesCP.xlsx';
V=xlsread('DriveCyclesCP.xlsx',2,'C9:C774'); % Get the velocity values, they are in an   array V.
N=length(V);                  % Find out how many readings
mass = 1700 ;                 % Vehicle mass+ two 70 kg passengers.
area_Cd = 0.75;               % Frontal area in square metres
Crr=0.009;                    %rolling resistance
g=9.8;                        % gravity acceleration
T=774;                        %UDDS cycle time duration
V_ave = 21.5;                 % UDDS avearage speed im m/s
rd=0.3;                       % Effective tire radius
Qhv =12.22;                   % E85 low Heating value in kWh/kg
Vd = 2.189;                     % engine size in L 
md=0.801;                     %  mass density of Ethanol
mf =Vd*md;                    % mf is the fuel mass consumed per cycle

Per = zeros(1,N);             % engine power for each point of the drive cycle
a = zeros(1,N);               % acceleration 
SFC = zeros(1,N);             % specific fuel consumption
Wc = zeros (1,N);            % mass flow rate
nf = zeros (1,N);             %fuel efficiency
Pm = zeros (1,N);            % motor power
Pt = zeros (1,N);
Te =zeros (1,N);              % Engine Troque
Tt = zeros (1,N);
Tm =zeros (1,N);
we =zeros (1,N);              % Engine rot speed
wt = zeros (1,N);
wm =zeros (1,N);
S =zeros (1,8);
int (sym ('C'));

for C=1:N
    a(C)=V(C+1)-V(C);
    Pt(C)= V(C)*(mass*g*Crr + (0.5*area_Cd*1.202*(V(C))^2) + mass*a(C))/1000; 
    Per(C)=(mass*g*Crr +0.5*area_Cd*1.202*(V(C))^2 +mass*g*0.03)/1000*0.85;% e

    syms Te(C) Tt(C) Tm(C) wt(C) we(C) wm(C) k1 k2

    S = solve( Pm(C)==Pt(C) - Per(C), Tt(C)*wt(C)== Pt(C), Tt(C)*wt(C)==  Te(C)*we(C) +      Tm(C)*wm(C), wt(C)==we(C)/k1,  wt(C)==wm(C)/k2, Pm(C)==wm(C) *Tm(C), Per(C)==we(C) *Te(C), Tt == k1*Te + k2*Tm );

end
```

Comment: What is the output of `which sym`?

Comment: What is the point of this line: `int (sym ('C'));`? What is the entire error message, i.e., what line does it occur at?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is on the line

```
int (sym ('C'));
```

You have defined `sym` to be a matrix with 2 entries somewhere (either earlier in the code or in a previous mfile), thus it treats `sym` as a matrix instead of a function.  Thus when Matlab gets to the statement `sym('C')` it first converts the character `'C'` to its [ASCII](http://www.ascii-code.com/) integer representation (this just happens to be the number 67), then it tries to calculate `sym(67)` which is impossible as `sym` only has 2 elements.

Thus you have to stop `sym` from being a matrix (variable) and let it be a function again.  There are two ways to solve this, either you can start you file with the statement `clear;`, this will remove all variables in memory, which might not be what you want; or you can use a [function instead of script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1695365/whats-the-difference-between-a-script-and-a-function-in-matlab/1695377#1695377), as this hides all variables that have been defined previously and prevents this sort of error.

Note the line `numel(X)` is a way to measure how many elements are in `X`.  Thus `numel(sym)=2` means that `sym` has 2 elements.

P.S. There is an error in the lines (notice that I only taken some of the lines of you code)

```
N=length(V);                  % Find out how many readings
for C=1:N
    a(C)=V(C+1)-V(C);
end
```

When `C` becomes equal to `N`, then `V(C+1)` will generate an error.